# Parallel programing in the functional paradigm

Tags: functional-programming, parallel-processing

I've been hearing some hype lately about using functional languages for parallel programing. I'm interested in learning more about this, but I haven't been able to find much material on the topic. Could someone recommend any good websites, books, research papers, etc on the subject?

Comment: Please re-word with a real question.

Comment: Can you also qualify which definition of "functional" you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map reduce which is likely the most dominant algorithm in use today is functional: http://labs.google.com/papers/mapreduce.html

There is the classic paper on software transactional memory: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/stm/stm.pdf

Well Clojure has plenty of real world examples: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=clojure+parallel

Just about everything having to do with Erlang is about parallelism.

Most stuff you would find searching under "Actor model" would be functional.

I guess my question would be what aren't you finding?

Comment: I think the problem was I was using the wrong key words. e.g. parallel programing with functional paradigm